# Update, Insert to sql .. There is already an open DataReader associated with

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

[image]

```
string[] stringList2 = new string[10];
if (VaildDataRow == true)
{                        
//Response.Write("<script>alert('2valid data row" + TbRow + "')</script>");
TbCol = 0;
TcCol = 1;
foreach (TableCell tc in tr.Cells)
{
#region //Load array with valid row text boxes' value
foreach (Control c1 in tc.Controls)
{
if (c1 is TextBox)
{
if (c1.ID.StartsWith("DataTbFld_"))
{
TextBox txt = (TextBox)t11.FindControl(c1.ID);
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt.Text))
{
//Response.Write("<script>alert('txt#id ..not hidden..: " + txt.ID + " found data in textbox, rec is valid , will break')</script>");
txt.Text="Null";
}
stringList2[TbCol] = txt.Text.ToString();
//Response.Write("<script>alert('TbRow : " + TbRow + " TcCol : " + TcCol + " TbCol : " + TbCol + " txt.Text.ToString() : " + txt.Text.ToString() + "')</script>");
}
TbCol += 1;
}                          
}
#endregion//===
TcCol += 1;
}
Response.Write("<script>alert('TbRow : " + TbRow + "')</script>");
#region //if exist update else insert
Response.Write("<script>alert('InputDate = " + stringList2[6] + 
" and Dept= " + stringList2[7] + " and DeptType= " + stringList2[8] + 
" and DeptSubType= " + stringList2[9] + "')</script>");
con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM MainDailyData WHERE Dept= '" + stringList2[7] + "' and DeptType = '" + stringList2[8] + "' and DeptSubType= '" + stringList2[9] + "'", con);

dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (dr != null && dr.HasRows)
{
Response.Write("<script>alert('Found,Update')</script>");
SqlDataAdapter myda = new SqlDataAdapter();
myda.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE MainDailyData SET Product1 = @Prod1, Product2 = @Prod2, Product3 = @Prod3, Product4 = @Prod4, Product5 = @Prod5, Product6 = @Prod6, InputDate = @InDate, Dept = @Dpt, DeptType = @DptType, DeptSubType = @DptSubType", con);
myda.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[0];
myda.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[1];
myda.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod3", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[2];
myda.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod4", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[3];
myda.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod5", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[4];
myda.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod6", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[5];
myda.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@InDate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[6];
myda.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Dpt", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[7];
myda.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@DptType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[8];
myda.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@DptSubType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[9];
//dr.Close();
//con.Open();
myda.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
else
{
Response.Write("<script>alert('not Found,Insert')</script>");
SqlDataAdapter myda = new SqlDataAdapter();
myda.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO MainDailyData (Product1,Product2,Product3,Product4,Product5,Product6,InputDate,Dept,DeptType,DeptSubType) VALUES(@Prod1,@Prod2,@Prod3,@Prod4,@Prod5,@Prod6,@InDate,@Dpt,@DptType,@DptSubType)", con);
myda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[0];
myda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[1];
myda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod3", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[2];
myda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod4", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[3];
myda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod5", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[4];
myda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod6", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[5];
myda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@InDate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[6];
myda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Dpt", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[7];
myda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DptType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[8];
myda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DptSubType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[9];
//dr.Close();
//con.Open();
myda.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
con.Close();
#endregion
}
#endregion
TbRow += 1;
}
```

when excauting

```
myda.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

or

```
myda.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

i got error msg
There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

if I close dr the result will be messy. If it found record in row 2 of the table, it will insert record of row 1 from the table to the database
i tried to enable MultipleActiveResultSets="true", but i got a problem attribute is not allowed!

I want to check if record exist, update else ,insert. how to achieve this or how to correct my code?

after edition:

```
#region //if exist update else insert inserting code
//Response.Write("<script>alert('InputDate = " + stringList2[6] + 
//" and Dept= " + stringList2[7] + " and DeptType= " + stringList2[8] + 
//" and DeptSubType= " + stringList2[9] + "')</script>");
con.Open();
//cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT 1 FROM MainDailyData WHERE Dept= '" + stringList2[7] + 
//    "' and DeptType = '" + stringList2[8] + "' and DeptSubType= '" + stringList2[9] + "'", con);
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT 1 FROM MainDailyData WHERE Dept= @dpt and DeptType = @dptType and DeptSubType= @DptSbType", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dpt", stringList2[7]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dptType", stringList2[8]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DptSbType", stringList2[9]);

bool fRecordExists = false;
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
//SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if (dr != null && dr.HasRows)
{
fRecordExists = true;
}
dr.Close();
dr.Dispose();
if (fRecordExists)
{
Response.Write("<script>alert('Found,Update')</script>");
SqlDataAdapter myda = new SqlDataAdapter();
myda.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE MainDailyData SET Product1 = @Prod1, Product2 = @Prod2, Product3 = @Prod3, Product4 = @Prod4, Product5 = @Prod5, Product6 = @Prod6, InputDate = @InDate, Dept = @Dpt, DeptType = @DptType, DeptSubType = @DptSubType", con);
myda.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[0];
myda.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[1];
myda.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod3", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[2];
myda.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod4", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[3];
myda.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod5", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[4];
myda.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod6", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[5];
myda.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@InDate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[6];
myda.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Dpt", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[7];
myda.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@DptType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[8];
myda.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@DptSubType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[9];
myda.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
else
{
Response.Write("<script>alert('not Found,Insert')</script>");
SqlDataAdapter myda = new SqlDataAdapter();
myda.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO MainDailyData (Product1,Product2,Product3,Product4,Product5,Product6,InputDate,Dept,DeptType,DeptSubType) VALUES(@Prod1,@Prod2,@Prod3,@Prod4,@Prod5,@Prod6,@InDate,@Dpt,@DptType,@DptSubType)", con);
myda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[0];
myda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[1];
myda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod3", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[2];
myda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod4", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[3];
myda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod5", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[4];
myda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prod6", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[5];
myda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@InDate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[6];
myda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Dpt", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[7];
myda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DptType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[8];
myda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DptSubType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stringList2[9];
myda.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
con.Close();
#endregion
```

still the problem exist for updating or inserting the second row, if i fill 1st first record and leave the second empty, it will insert it to the db but will not eccept any inserting later to the second row, instead it will duplicate the 1st row record. interchangablly, for if i fill the the second row first. if i fill both if them @ the begining it will insert them both but will not recognize the second record and will duplicate the first record?

Comment: You must either create a new connection, or close the existing reader before you do any other command using the same connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just close the dr immediately after you determine whether or not it has any results; you aren't using it for anything other than determining if the record exists or not, so this won't affect your logic at all.

Replace:

```
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (dr != null && dr.HasRows)
```

with:

```
        bool fRecordExists = false;
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr != null && dr.HasRows)
        {
            fRecordExists = true;
        }
        dr.Close();
        if (fRecordExists)
```

You should also change the select statement to a parameterized query to prevent SQL injection attacks and exceptions due to unexpected characters in the data.

Also, the select statement, if it isn't going to be used for anything other than existence verification, should just do `SELECT 1` instead of `SELECT *` to prevent unneeded processing in both the database and application.

Finally, if your application data supports it (i.e. the select criteria will only select 1 record at the max), I would suggest using [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) instead of `ExecuteReader`, which would eliminate your problem altogether.

Comment: Thanks brothers that really solved it but as I experienced before I met strange situation when I try to edit both records It tells me that record at row 3 in the table is found and it update it successfully but record at row 4 it tells me that it is not found, while it's there and further more it insert record in row 3 of the table which diplacate the record. I believe it should not mix between them as i'm using array to submit to the db.